# How to call a Style Property setter of another property that is set in in the same style in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am writing a style in a user control to control the styles of single axes from a collection of axes. This all works but now I want to integrate a rotation of the AxisTitle.
But if I do the following (only title setter is shown):

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<Style x:Key="AxisStyle" TargetType="myLib:AxisBase">
    <Setter Property="AxisTitle" Value="{Binding Title, Mode=OneWay}" />
    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then the rotation is applied to the axisbase which is all of the axis not just the title. (I understand why)
But how can I change the code so that this RenderTransform applies to the AxisTitle?

What works if I do it to a specific instance of axis is the following:

```
<Resources>
    <Style x:Key="AxisTitleStyle" TargetType="myLib:AxisTitle">
        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Resources>

<Axis Style="{StaticResource AxisTitleStyle>/>
```

But I would like to put it to the styling of AxisBase to style the title inside.
**Q:** Is this possible?

This is only the first step to what I finally want to achieve. A property dependant rotation like this (pseudo code):

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Axis.RotateTitle}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </DataTrigger>

    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Axis.RotateTitle}" Value="False">
    <!-- Do nothing -->
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

But first I have to find out how to set the RenderTransform to the AxisTitle inside the Style.

Answer (score 0):

I would, of course, have to see the Axis visual tree to know for sure what you want, but it sounds like you want to apply the transform to the xaml element that is bound to the axis title inside Axis.  Axis, no doubt, is a visual tree that you can take apart with Blend pretty easily (Edit Existing Template).

Once you have the full, existing style template for Axis, you can tweak the bit that actually refers/binds to the title so that a transform can be dynamically applied.  Hope that helps...

Comment: Its a 3rd party control. Blend and Studio don't create a template for the Axis. Only for the control itself. I can't find any axis.

Comment: Regardless of who creates the control, there is a visual tree of the Axis right? You can view it using Snoop. You can extract the style with Blend no matter what.  All of this is presuming Axis is a wpf control...

Comment: I stumbled upon the property to set. It is TitleStyle and I got it to work. With this knowledge I searched for it in Snoop (still can't get Blend to do what you said, but probably because its the first time I used it :) ). From what I see now I couldn't deduct how to correctly do it the way I am doing it now. Only with the knowledge I have now I can find it in snoop at all. Note: I am rather new to WPF.

Comment: Well, that's what Snoop is for :)  Glad you found a way to get it working.